# Breadcrumbs with asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to provide breadcrumb navigation for my application. I have 3 controllers - Project, Task & TaskDetail.

I need to show the breadcrumb something like

Projects > Project Details > Tasks > Task Details

Below is my Mvc.sitemap file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Projects" controller="Project" action="ProjectList">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Project Details" controller="Project" action="Details"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

my Project controller

```
public ActionResult ProjectList()
{
 ///logic to show all projects list
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
 ///logic to show details of a project
}
```

this is my Task controller

```
public ActionResult TaskList(int projectId)
{
 ///logic to show all tasks of the selected project
}

public ActionResult TaskDetails(int id)
{
 ///logic to show details of a task
}
```

When I navigate to the ProjectList action method, I get the breadcrumb as

```
 Projects
```

but when I navigate to Details(in project controller) I don't even see the breadcrumb

Kindly help me what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks
Tarak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the "Project Details" mvcSiteMapNode inside of your "Projects" mvcSiteMapNode.

Change your MVC.sitemap code to this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Projects" controller="Project" action="ProjectList"/>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Project Details" controller="Project" action="Details"/>
</mvcSiteMap>
```